# Sort by date in Looker Studio (DataStudio)

Tags: looker-studio

so I am facing this issue with sorting the data, in the table, by the date. The thing is that I had to change format so that I can see the all together **Day of Week, Date, Hour, Minute**.

FORMAT_DATETIME("%a %d.%m.%y. %H:%M",**MY DATE**)

which caused that the sorting is now done alphabetically and the variable is treated as a text and not a date anymore.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldAlZ.png)

Is there any way to include all information and be able to sort by date?

Answer (score 0):

In the Looker Studio documentation (https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/9730334?hl=en) we find that `FORMAT_DATETIME` converts a date to formatted text.
Try to use `PARSE_DATETIME` (converts text to a date with time)

If you don't have the seconds part simulate them `PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', CONCAT(DT_ATTRIBUTE, ':00'))`

Comment: I am not sure if I understand it correctly, nevertheless with PARSE_DATETIME('%f',FORMAT_DATETIME("%a %d.%m.%y. %H:%M",MY DATE)) my date disappears for the whole column